# copy folder/files from one branch to another branch in different directory

Tags: git

On branch A there are 3 added header files and one directory I want to copy over to branch B while also changing the location in which they are stored on branch B.

**Branch A:**

```
.
├── include
│   ├── some_header.h <-- copy this
│   ├── some_header.h <--- and this
│   └── yet_another_header.h <-- and this
├── src
│   ├── dir_in_question <-- copy this whole directory with contents
│   │   ├── libxx.cpp
│   │   └── index.html
│   ..
..
```

**Branch B:** they should go here:

```
.
├── client <-- new directory on branch B
│   ├── some_header.h
│   ├── some_header.h
│   │── yet_another_header.h
│   ├── dir_in_question
│   │   ├── libxx.cpp
│   │   └── index.html
├── src
│   │
│   ..
..
```

How can I do that? All the other solutions on the net just talk about keeping the same worktree.

Comment: If you've committed the changes to branch A, you could cherry pick them into branch B. This would however require that you didn't bunch all your commits into single ones

Comment: @SimonC But wouldn't that mean that the directory stays the same? Also, what if more files were added in the commit, it would also import those right?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing would be to be on target branch, then do a restore using the other branch as source, then move and add into the local branch.... this, however, does imply that you have **no** relation to the source branch... git won't know where it came from[1].... it's as if you sat down to write the files from scratch.

```
git checkout target-branch
git restore --worktree --source source-branch -- some-directory-from-source-branch
mv some-directory-from-source-branch real-location-where-i-want-it
git add real-location-where-i-want-it
```

That should suffice.

[1] The fact that git does now know where it came from is not too big of a problem, anyway.... you might even cherry-pick commits involving those files from source-branch on the target branch later on.... git would be able to see that the files were renamed (if they are not too different from what the files look like in the source branch, that is... there is a *difference* threshold involved in that process) and apply the change accordingly.